# Possible to make distinctions in VAT for business/private in Paypal?

Tags: paypal

To comply with VAT rules in my home country I need to set up a system where my customers are charged the right VAT amount when they purchase something on my site and I was wondering if this is possible from inside Paypal.

In the PayPal configuration pages, I can set a VAT percentage per country. This is however not sufficient, according to the laws here I need to charge:

- 21% to ANYONE from my own country (that's the Netherlands)
- 0% to anyone outside the EU
- For all other EU countries, I need to charge 21% if they are a private person, 0% if they are a business (have a VAT number).

Would it be possible to set something up in Paypal so that EU-business customers can fill in their VAT-number and are charged 0%? If not, would it be possible to add an extra field where customers pay, that only shows up for people logging in from within the EU (saying that they need to contact us if they want a VAT-free transaction)?

Hope anyone could help with this..thanks in advance for any time taken!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem complying with new EU VAT law. I used Taxamo to solve this.